# How can I change the country of an iTunes account?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, itunes-store

When I first set up my iTunes account, I didn't have a credit card, so I set it up as a US account, as this was the only way I could create one without a card (and thus use my iPod Touch).

The downside of this is that now that I am trying to add a credit card to my iTunes account, I can't, because it insists on a state and zip code for part of the address, which my Irish credit card obviously doesn't have.

So how can I switch the country of my iTunes account?

Comment: I have the same problem. I long time ago created my apple account, not because of iTunes, but because I'm a developer. Yesterday I wanted to try out the new iTunes features and my country was set to US and couldn't be changed to Denmark. I didn't manage to solve it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To change stores you can do so on the iTunes Store:

1. Click on your Account in the iTunes Store to go to your Account Page.
2. Click "Change Country or Region".
    [image: iTunes Screenshot]
3. Choose your Country or Region:
    [image: iTunes Screenshot 2]

Another alternative is to use Apple's [Manage your Apple ID site](https://appleid.apple.com) and change your address - next time you use iTunes it will ask you to change your region and verify your address details.

Comment: Problem in step 1. My account haven't yet been used with iTunes, so iTunes asks me to review my account information and offers me no way to change the country. So I never get to step 1. But my problem is probably different from the original poster.

Comment: @neoneye: Check my edit - I forgot about the My Apple ID page the first time around.

Comment: No solution yet. I tried via the My Apple ID site to change Preferred Language from English to Danish. The shipping address is already set to denmark. When I afterwards try to sign in via iTunes I still can't change the country.

Comment: @neoneye: Sounds like you'll have to contact support and they can take care of it for you.

Comment: yeah, I should do that. Was just hoping for an easy solution when I saw this thread that someone may be in the same situation as me. Thanks for the help

Comment: There is one gotcha: if you purchased anything one the original country, then you can't access it via the App Store after changing the country of your account.

Comment: @Sylvain’s point cannot be stressed enough: I’ve just lost all my purchases. *Slow clap* … well done, Apple.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: You're purchase are not lost, you can still change back to the old country. But you lose your new purchases ...

Comment: @Sylvain The point is that I cannot access all purchases at the same time, which is a major hurdle for me at the moment. Well, “major” … I simply don’t use the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I search some and find this video I think it is helpful but most notice it's not test on iTunes 10 you must try it yourself and tell the result.

[here is the link of video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZLScy599mI)