# How to know which iOS apps are restricted to a country?

Tags: ios, itunes, applications, ios-appstore

I'm actually using an US iTunes account, but I'm interested in switching my country to another (as people suggest [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/how-to-change-country-of-an-itunes-account)) to my original country to be able to use my credit card (with address in my country).

The problem is that I may have apps only available in the US App Store, and probably I don't really care about those apps but I would like to know which are those apps to be sure if I could live without them.

Do you know how or where to check that?
If it's something automatic, would be great, but if I need to look each of my apps it's not a problem at all.

Comment: I bet there's something automatic, because of the existence of this: http://appshopper.com/ - though it does not filter by country (I've tested changing the dropbox in the bottom, and it still shows apps that are not available at my country), it does scan the whole store and it's my opinion it presents app in a much better way than apple store itself. Anyways, to who is going to try and answer this question, there are many sites like this out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of anything automatic - but you can browse the iTunes store here:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/browse

This is the US store - if you browse to your app, and then replace the 'us' part of the URL with the country code for the store you want to check (e.g. 'fr' for france, 'ie' for Ireland, etc) - you'll either get brought to the entry for the App in that country, or get an error message that the app is not available.

I don't think you'll find a huge number of apps that aren't available.

If you use Apple TV, do consider that the films/TV choices in other stores may be much more limited.

You might want to consider keeping two accounts rather than changing. It can make management a little more inconvenient, but you'll have a bigger choice of things to buy/rent.

Comment: Using two accounts sounds interesting, but I may be able to sync two accounts at the same time for my devices? I mean, have the apps for two accounts in same devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between accounts whenever you want. All the existing apps and data will remain on your iPhone when switching iTunes App Store account.