# Transferring purchases to different store

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

I made some purchases on the Egyptian store, now i'm on the US store and the items that i purchased is no longer available unless i switched back to the Egyptian store. Is there a way that I can use different stores but still can download the same items that I purchased in different stores ?

Answer (score 3):

Transfers cannot be made from one Apple ID to another Apple ID. Although you can switch the store region preference for your Apple ID to select different regions and download the region specific applications. Use this guide to [change the region/store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/how-can-i-change-the-country-of-an-itunes-account).